# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints VS androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, layout

When I try to change the main Layout of `activity_main.xml`, then I see a pop-up of two layouts with the similar name of Constraint.

So please tell me difference between  `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints` VS `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` .

Comment: There is nothing named `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints` in the SDK. There is an `androidx.work.Constraints` class (constraints for work performed by `WorkManager`). There is an `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet` class (constraints for a `ConstraintLayout`). There is an `androidx.ui.core.Constraints` class (constraints for use with Jetpack Compose). None of these are layouts.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks man, now i understand that first one is not layout. "Happy Coding"